# Activity crashes when paused

Tags: android, multithreading, canvas, android-activity, android-intent

I have an activity that keeps crashing onPause. Theres a looped thread that draws on a canvas. And When I paused the application or try to move to another activity it crashes.

I have it so it closes out onPause, because I don't want it to post a force close. But I want to be able to go back to the activity

```
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    boolean retry = true;
    _canDraw = false;
    while(retry) {
        try {
            DrawThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} 

@Override 
protected void onDestroy() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onDestroy();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}

@Override 
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.face_button:
        _canDraw = false;
        try {
            DrawThread.join();
            whack.this.startActivity(selectFace);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
@Override 
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
}
```

You're wondering why it crashes onPause? You're crashing it.

Comment: I said I put that their to avoid posting the error. Regardless it still crashes and I found something earlier saying activity not found. I don't have the workspace here so I cant do much yet.

Comment: And it doesn't crash onpause without the killprocess it crashes when it tries to resume.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't find a hint in your question that you added an exception per purpose to avoid posting the real error. And if we should help you, it would be better if you tell us that onResume is the problem and not onPause.

Comment: Relax, I didn't even understand what the problem was when I was writing this. I did state that right here "I have it so it closes out onPause, because I don't want it to post a force close" The real problem was the Manifest. I called the activity something else.